# php inserting to database fail

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I have following message box error, says **Failed**. these are my codes:

```
<?php   
require('admin/connectdb.php');
    if (isset($_POST['Sub'])) 
    {   

        //get data from reservation form 
        $cutomername=$_POST['aname'];
        $gender=$_POST['sex'];
        $phoneno=$_POST['tel'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $age=$_POST['age'];
        $computerpart=$_POST['partcomp'];
        $option1=$_POST['option1'];
        $notes=$_POST['Notes'];

        $query="INSERT INTO `assignmentwebprog`.`reservation` (`cumstomername`, `gender`, `phoneno`, `email`, `age`, `typeofcomputerpart`, `option`, `notes`) 
                    VALUES ('$cutomername', '$gender', '$phoneno', '$email', '$age', '$computerpart', '$option1', '$notes')";
        $qresult = mysql_query($query);
        if ($qresult){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

up there is inserting value to phpmyadmin & every time i load/input then click enter then the page shows message box "failed"
these are my database:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // username
$username="root"; // username
$db_name="assignmentwebprog"; //database name
$tbl_name="reservation";
// Replace database connect functions depending on database you are using.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
?>
```

currently my database is phpmyadmin, is there something missing with my code?

Comment: don't use mysql_* function its deprecated use PDO instead

Comment: remove double qua-toes from mysql_connect and mysql_select_db

Comment: It's deprecated but temporarily use `echo mysql_error();` before `if` to get potential sql errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the field in the database `cumstomername` is spelt correctly.
It should probably be `customername`

**Passing the paramter**

```
$cutomername=$_POST['aname'];
```

**SQL**

```
$query="INSERT INTO `assignmentwebprog`.`reservation` (`cumstomername`, `gender`, `phoneno`, `email`, `age`, `typeofcomputerpart`, `option`, `notes`) 
                    VALUES ('$cutomername', '$gender', '$phoneno', '$email', '$age', '$computerpart', '$option1', '$notes')";
```

Comment: Check to see if the field `customnername` is spelled correctly. It should probably be `customername`, please check your spelling :)

Comment: but now they say alert('submitted successfully!')"; } else { echo ""; } } ?> what is that thing?

Comment: If you only corrected the field and the rest of the code of your initial questions stayed the same then I can't see why it would just show the message. Can you see a record in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and try:

```
$qresult = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
$query="INSERT INTO reservation (cumstomername, gender, phoneno, email, age, typeofcomputerpart, option, notes) 
                    VALUES ('$cutomername', '$gender', '$phoneno', '$email', '$age', '$computerpart', '$option1', '$notes')";
        $qresult = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have missing something in the $query which is mandatory for the table insertion.

First echo the query on the page. // echo $query ;

Then RUN the query in phpmyadmin and you will get the reason why it is not inserting in the table. See the error there.